# cocos2d-x disable screen capture android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.2 and I want to block screen capture.
I found FLAG_SECURE can block screen capture,
but cocos2d-x sometimes captured screen ignoring this flag.
I think this caused by using Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.
Is there any solution to block screen capture? thanks.

Comment: you mean disabling touch ?

Comment: no I mean screenshot.